# Deferring a computation in custom object until data available

Tags: python

I have a custom class like the below.  The idea, as the naming suggests, is that I want to evaluate a token stream in a parser-type tool.  Once a bunch of constructs have been parsed out and put into data structures, certain sequences of tokens will evaluate to an int, but when the data structures aren't available yet, a function just returns None instead.  This single complex data structure 'constructs' gets passed around pretty much everywhere in the program.

```
class Toks(list):
    def __init__(self, seq, constructs=Constructs()):
        list.__init__(self, seq)
        self.constructs = constructs
    @property
    def as_value(self):
        val = tokens_as_value(self, self.constructs)
        return val if val is not None else self
```

At points in the code, I want to assign this maybe-computable value to a name, e.g.:

```
mything.val = Toks(tokens[start:end], constructs).as_value
```

Well, this gives `mything.val` either an actual int value or a funny thing that allows us to compute a value later.  But this requires a later pass to actually perform the computation, similar to:

```
if not isinstance(mything.val, int):
    mything.val = mything.val.as_value
```

As it happens, I *can* do this in my program.  However, what I'd really like to happen is to avoid the second pass altogether, and just have access to the property perform the computation and give the computed value if it's computable at that point (and perhaps evaluate to some sentinal if it's not possible to compute).

Any ideas?

---

To clarify: Depending on the case I get "value" differently; actual code is more like:

```
if tok.type == 'NUMBER':
    mything.val = tok.value  # A simple integer value
else:
    mything.val = Toks(tokens[start:end], constructs).as_value
```

There are additional cases, sometimes I know I know the actual value early, and sometimes I'm not sure if I'll only know it later.

I realize I can defer calling (a bit more compactly than @dana suggests) with:

```
return val if val is not None else lambda: self.as_value
```

However, that makes later access inconsistent between `mything.val` and `mything.val()`, so I'd still have to guard it with an `if` to see which style to use.  It's the same inconvenience whether I need to fall back to `mything.val.as_value` or to `mything.val()` after the type check.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do something like:

```
class NaiveLazy(object):
    def __init__(self, ctor):
        self.ctor = ctor
        self._value = None
    @property
    def value(self):
        if self._value is None:
            self._value = ctor()
        return self._value
mything = NaiveLazy(lambda: time.sleep(5) and 10)
```

And then always use mything.value (example to demonstrate evaluation):

```
print mything.value # will wait 5 seconds and print 10
print mything.value # will print 10
```

I've seen some utility libraries create a special object for undefined in case ctor returns `None`. If you eventually want to extend your code beyond ints, you should think about that:

```
class Undefined(object): pass
UNDEFINED = Undefined()
#...
self._value = UNDEFINED
#...
if self._value is UNDEFINED: self._value = ctor()
```

For your example specifically:

```
def toks_ctor(seq, constructs=Constructs()):
    return lambda l=list(seq): tokens_as_value(l, constructs) or UNDEFINED

mything = NaiveLazy(toks_ctor(tokens[start:end], constructs))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python3.2+, consider a [Future](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#future-objects) object. This tool lets you run any number of calculations in the background. You can wait for a single future to be completed, and use its value.  Or, you can "stream" the results one at a time as they're completed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm trapped on 2.7.x for this project.  However, a `Future` isn't really the right thing here either.  It's not that the computation needs to run in the background, it's that it needs to run (in the same thread) once some various data is filled into data structures.  The computation itself is completely trivial, so much so there's not actually any reason even to cache it, for example.

Comment: I was hoping that the Future object would fit your needs: you can tell if it's computable or not.  It's been backported to 2.7: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures   I'll be curious at the solution you pick!

Comment: I think the interface for `Future` really is quite elegant.  I suppose in a sense I _could_ use that, since the whole process in single threaded and a background thread that just kept trying to fill in a value if the needed data becomes available would just utilize another core without slowing down the main program.  But it's really not like I'm waiting on some I/O, nor waiting on a long-running computation.  It's always a trivial computation I do, the issue is the dynamic flow of the program, and what data structures have been (ultimately sequentially) populated.

Answer (score 0):

You could return a callable object from `as_value`, which would allow you automatically check for the real return value automatically. The one drawback is you'd need to use `mything.val()` instead of `mything.val`:

```
def tokens_as_value(toks, constructs):
    if constructs.constructed:
        return "some value"
    else:
        return None

class Constructs(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.constructed = False

class Toks(list):
    def __init__(self, seq, constructs=Constructs()):
        list.__init__(self, seq)
        self.constructs = constructs

    @property
    def as_value(self):
        return FutureVal(tokens_as_value, self, self.constructs)

class FutureVal(object):
    def __init__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        self.func = func
        self._val = None
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __call__(self):
        if self._val is None:
            self._val = self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        return self._val
```

Just for the purposes of the example, `Constructs` just contains a boolean that indicates whether or not a real value should be returned from `tokens_as_value`.

Usage:

```
>>> t = test.Toks([])
>>> z = t.as_value
>>> z
<test.FutureVal object at 0x7f7292c96150>
>>> print(z())
None
>>> t.constructs.constructed = True
>>> print(z())
our value
```